# Include() only specific property

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Here I am retrieving items and including the creator of the item. The goal is to include only the first and last name from the creator, not the entire user model.

```
var items = _db.Items.Include("Creator")
```

The item model has `Creator` as a navigation property like this:

```
      public User Creator { get; set; }
```

It works fine, but it loads the entire user model, when really I just want the first name and last name.

How do I specify I only want specific property returned from the user model?

Comment: You can't materialize an entity object with only a subset of properties. This could create invalid entities. You have to project to another class, anonymous or named. It's common to define DTO or view model classes for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that using `Include`. You can use `Select` instead:

```
var items = _db.Items.Select(i => new { Item = i, Creator = new { i.Creator.FirstName, i.Creator.LastName } });
```

**Update**

If you need to return that query as method result you have to create a class which could hold the results:

```
public class ItemWithCreatorNames
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public string CreatorFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CreatorLastName { get; set; }
}

var items = _db.Items.Select(i => new ItemWithCreatorNames { Item = i, CreatorFirstName  = i.Creator.FirstName, CreatorLastName  = i.Creator.LastName });
```

Comment: How do i return that as IQueryable? I seem to be missing a step